# Is it possible to bulk_update a many-to-many relationship in django 2.2?

Tags: django, many-to-many, bulk, bulkupdate

I have these two simple models:

```
class school(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class teacher(models.Model):
    schools = models.ManyToManyField(School)
    user = models.OneToOneField(...)
```

In a view, let's say I want to add a school to multiple teachers at the same time. I could do something like this:

```
for teacher in teachers:
    teacher.schools.add(school)
```

This works, but it is making a lot of queries. Is there a better way to do something like this? I am using **django 2.2** (so maybe I could use bulk_update?).

Comment: you mean `teacher.schools.add(school)` (and you don't need to save `teacher`).

Comment: Yes, I've updated it, my bad :P

Comment: Django has a [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method, but you need the model and in this case the intermediate model (the one with the fk to `teacher` and to `school`) is hidden. If you can get to the class, you could use bulk_create, but I don't have all `teacher._meta` methods on the top of my head, although I'm sure there's a way to get that class.

Comment: Note that if you just have a dozen of teachers or so, there's no harm in having so many queries. They are pretty simple ones, shouldn't happen very often, and django will all send them through the same db connection,  so why worry?

Comment: Yeah, in this specific scenario, I agree that this probably wouldn't be such a big deal. But the same situation could apply on other relationships which could deal with way more objects. It could have a bigger impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

In short you should be able to use:

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name="foo")
```

You can also use F objects to do things like incrementing rows:

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.all().update(n_pingbacks=F('n_pingbacks') + 1)
```

See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

However, note that:

- This won't use ModelClass.save method (so if you have some logic
  inside it won't be triggered).
- No django signals will be emitted.

Comment: I don't think this applies to my situation.